# How do I run tailwindcss programatically?

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css

I want to process the sample input:

```
@tailwind base;@tailwind components;@tailwind utilities;
```

programatically. How could I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the PostCSS API to programmatically run Tailwind:

```js
const postcss = require('postcss');
const tailwindcss require('tailwindcss');
const baseConfig = require('./tailwind.config');

const sourceCSS = '@tailwind base; @tailwind components; @tailwind utilities';
const config = {
  presets:[baseConfig],
};
postcss([tailwindcss(config)])
  .process(sourceCSS)
  .then((css) => {
    // `css` is a string of the compiled CSS.
  });
```